# How to render a list of icons, always incrementing one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still a beginner in JavaScript and ReactJS. I'm doing a project to improve my knowledge.

I'm rendering a list where the user can filter results by star, as shown in the image below:

[image]

The way I created this list is not at all smart:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import StarBorderIcon from "@material-ui/icons/StarBorder";
import { useStyles } from "./styles";

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Start</h1>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Checkbox />
        <StarBorderIcon />
      </div>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Checkbox />
        <StarBorderIcon />
        <StarBorderIcon />
      </div>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Checkbox />
        <StarBorderIcon />
        <StarBorderIcon />
        <StarBorderIcon />
      </div>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Checkbox />
        <StarBorderIcon />
        <StarBorderIcon />
        <StarBorderIcon />
        <StarBorderIcon />
      </div>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Checkbox />
        <StarBorderIcon />
        <StarBorderIcon />
        <StarBorderIcon />
        <StarBorderIcon />
        <StarBorderIcon />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Can you tell me how to render this list, up to a total of 5 stars (as shown in the image), always adding one star to my list?

I put my code into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/render-stars-icon-k69fl?file=/src/App.js)

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and map over an array of specified length in order to create the individual sections and stars.

I'm using `new Array(number).fill(null)` since I want to create an array of a certain length and map over it. The `.fill(null)` is to get rid of the special `empty` values in an array constructed like this so that they are mapable.

You could have the logic all in one place, or you could convert pieces of the logic to separate components to simplify your main component.

Essentially in this we have 2 nested loops to render the checkboxes and the appropriate stars. The same is true whether you move the sub loop into it's own component (the Stars component in this example).

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import StarBorderIcon from "@material-ui/icons/StarBorder";
import { useStyles } from "./styles";
const array = new Array(5).fill(null);
export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Start</h1>
      {array.map((_val, idx) => (
        <div key={idx} className={classes.root}>
          <Checkbox />
          {new Array(idx + 1).fill(null).map((_val, idx2) => (
            <StarBorderIcon key={idx2} />
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
      {/* Move some logic to a separate component */}
      {array.map((_val, idx) => (
        <div key={idx} className={classes.root}>
          <Checkbox />
          <Stars number={idx + 1} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function Stars({ number }) {
  return new Array(number)
    .fill(null)
    .map((_val, idx) => <StarBorderIcon key={idx} />);
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/render-stars-icon-forked-wxtx4?file=/src/App.js